# Countable/Uncountable discrete question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I asked this question before but I missed type it. If $E$ is uncountable and $S ⊆  E$ is countable, Is $E / S$ countable? Prove your solution.

i think it is uncountable since $E$ is uncountable. how can I prove it if it is true?

Comment: Assume by contradiction that it is countable, and show that it isn't.

Comment: Second thought, in its current format, this question requires a mere counterexample. So just take $E=\mathbb{R}$ and $S=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Prove by contraposition so that we suppose that $E \backslash S$ is countable.

Since $S$ is countable, then $(E \backslash S) \cup S$ is also countable. And clearly E is a subset of this set! So it must be countable.

Comment: Is it set difference? IMO / means quotient

Answer (score 0):

1.We have $E=S \cup (E \setminus S)$

2.The union of two countable sets is countable.

Answer (score 0):

$E\setminus S$ is not countable. Take $S$ to be the empty set $\emptyset$.